# Xcode 10.2.1 Simulators are not working

Tags: mac, xcode, simulator

after updating to xcode 10.2.1 simulators are not working. I'm using macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4 in my Mac mini (Late 2012). The Simulators takes 20-30 mins to attach to the apps and after waiting for that much it gives error messages like `could not attach to pid:980`, `could not attach to pid:1020`, `DTServiceHubClient failed to bless service hub for simulator`.

After this error message system starts lagging, performance slows down drastically.

I tried everything, Cleaning build folder, resetting simulator, reinstall xcode, updated mac OS, checked the host.txt file it includes localhost line, ping is also right. Please help me I have no idea what to do.

This error comes up often:

[image: Error1]

This is another error that appears frequently:

[image: Error2]

Comment: You may need to close xcode, kill all simulator processes with `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` and then reopen xcode.

Comment: Any luck on getting this resolve?  I'm getting the same error *everytime*!

Comment: No nothing works. I guess you can delete everything and try to freshly install the OS. But in my case I don't have permission to do that so I am just using a different machine.

Comment: Update: I installed extra 8GB ram now everything is working fine.